# What is the grammatical function of 'so' in this example?

Tags: grammar

"Mary is so funny."

What is the grammatical function of 'so' in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an adverb, qualifying the adjective “funny”. It is synonymous with *extremely* or *very much*.