# So do I ( what word type is "so" functioning as?

Tags: word-order

In the following example: 
I like cakes. So do I.

What word type is "so" taking the role of? Verb, adverb?

I understand that there is some ellipsis happening and the sentences could be re-written:

I like cakes. So do I like cakes.

Apologies if this is a very basic question, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/what-is-the-grammatical-function-of-so-in-this-example . 'so' is very complicated, it could be considered a pronoun or an adverb (but usually just an adverb).

Comment: What @Mitch said. Which effectively means "It's a matter of opinion", and I honestly don't see how such a rarefied discussion can usefully help an OP who presents **I like cakes. So do I like cakes.** as an "example usage".

Comment: To @FumbleFinger's point, "so do I like cakes" is not grammatical. I don't see any way to permits those five words or add any to make it so.

Comment: It's a little word that certainly punches above its weight!

Comment: How can "so" be a verb?? Can you say: I so, you so, he soes? By the way, every dictionary would give you the label adverb. But of course, not the structure of the formula. I would have explained it in a different way, but StoneyB's is better. Actually it is excellent.

Comment: Latin grammar has a special name for this special kind of adverbs of the type "as + adjective as. If I remember right the term is correlativa. Latin talis - qualis is literally "in such a way - in which way. An example of this old Latin formula would be: In which way a thing is better in such a way it is more expensive.

Answer (score 3):

*So `Aux NP`* -- as in *so do I, so are you, so has Mr. Smith* -- is a formulaic tag construction
that indicates a deletion, and must be preceded by a clause containing the deleted material.

- *You believe that he lost the race, and so do I.*
- *She's an idiot, and so are you.*
- *I've been there frequently, and so has Mr. Smith.*

In the first sentence, *so* replaces 'believe that he lost the race';
in the second, it replaces 'an idiot';
and in the third it replaces 'been there frequently'.

The order of the `Aux` and the *so* is reversed in this construction, the way it is in a tag question.
Normally *so* would follow the `Aux`, as it does in

- *I've always wanted to fill out my own tax forms, but I've never done so.*
  Here *so* replaces 'fill out my own tax forms'

All of these constituents that *so* replaces are [Verb Phrases (VPs)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).
If a pronoun like *it* can replace a noun,
and a pro-verb like *do* can replace a verb,
then the proper term for *so* is a pro-VP.

Comment: John, although in these cases *do* appears to behave like an Aux, it can also co-occur with other Auxes and in fact (more importantly I think) with Aux *do* itself: *I didn't do so.* (not *\*I didn't so*) So in these cases it's harder to say it's really an Aux (certainly it's not the same Aux of *do* support, which makes it harder to say that *so* itself is a pro-VP.

Comment: @AlanMunn: That's a different form of _do_, called Action _do_; it participates in a lot of specialized action constructions, like _do dishes/laundry, do damage, do a lot,_ etc. There's also emphatic _do_, as in _I **do** love you_. Act _do_ is a small verb, the other ones are auxiliary verbs.

Answer (score 2):

It's whatever your particular grammatical sect calls the word which introduces the back half of a comparative construction:

> [As you do,] so do I.

Just like "As Maine goes, so goes the nation".

Answer (score 2):

It's a pronoun of some sort.  The exact syntactic category of it is not so obvious, but it's very *unlikely* to be an adverb.

*do so* as a whole is a pro-verb-phrase, with *do* taking the place of the verb and *so* taking the place of its object.  We can see this when we ask questions about verb phrases. The question word that combines with *do* is *what* not *how*, which is what you would expect if *so* were an adverb. [Note that (2) has an irrelevant grammatical interpretation in which *do* means "fare" or the like, but this *do* is not the pro-verb *do*.]

1. *What did John do?*
2. **How did John do?* (≠ 1)

*So* can never appear conjoined with other adverbs:

3. *John solved the the problem quickly and carefully.*
4. *John solved the problem quickly* -> **Bill did so and sloppily*

*So* can never be intervened by a sentence adverb, which is a sign of a direct object (thanks to Greg Lee for reminding me of this test.)

5. **John solved willingly the problem.*
6. *John solved the problem willingly*
7. **Bill did willingly so.*
8. *Bill did so willingly.*

So the conclusion is that *so* is a pronoun of sorts that stands in for any category that could be the complement of the verb that *do* substitutes for.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an *adverb*.

In this context, *so* means something similar to “equally; in the same way; to the same extent”:

> He likes cakes; so do I.
>
> He likes cakes; I like them as much as he does.

Answer (score 0):

It's an adverb, modifying (expanding) "do." It's really an abbreviation of "also" when used this way, although I don't have an etymology reference to cite.

Rearrange the sentence and you'll see its function:
"I do also."

Comment: In fact it's the other way around, etymologically: *also* began as *all* + *swa*, "entirely so". (And eventually *alswa* wore down to modern *as*.)

Comment: I don’t think it means the same as “also”. “So” in this context means something like “equally; in the same way; to the same extent”. “Also”, by contrast, would mean something like “additionally; in addition to that”.

Comment: @StonyB - "all+so" is parallel to German "genau so" oder "ebensio".